# x-nautilus-desktop error message when opening Nautilus from desktop

Tags: gnome, nautilus, gvfs

Updated from 17.04 to 17.10. If I create a new Nautilus window from the desktop by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>, I get the following message:

> Sorry, could not display all the contents of "x-nautilus-desktop:///": The specified location is not supported.

Do I need `x-nautilus-desktop` bookmark and how can I get it working under Ubuntu 17.10 and Wayland?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same problem with fresh install of 17.10 when opening a new window of Nautilus using CTRL+N shortcut. **I avoid that message** creating an additional shortcut for Nautilus:

1. Go to keyboard settings, you should see the list of keyboard shortcuts.
2. Click on the "+" button at the bottom of that list to create a new shortcut.
3. Create a new shortcut filling the params asked:

   `Name = Open nautilus (or any other name you want)`

   `Command = nautilus (like when you open nautilus from terminal)`

   `Shortcut = Press the "Set Shortcut..." button and press **CTRL+M** (or any other combination you want).`

After setting the new shortcut for CTRL+M, close keyboard settings and the new shortcut will open nautilus without the "x-nautilus-desktop:///" error pointing to your home folder.

Hope this helps.

**EDIT (WARNING): The solution described helps to avoid the error mentioned, but not to solve the error itself.** If you try to overwrite the CTRL+N shortcut that will overwrite the shortcut for any other app. That is, for example, after CTRL+N overwriting in Google Chrome will open a new Nautilus window and not a new Chrome window. In my case, I set new Nautilus window to CTRL+M. This does not solve the "x-nautilus-desktop:///" error itself, but it's an alternative solution. If you set a new shortcut for Nautilus new window as CTRL+M, if you use CTRL+N you still get the error mentioned.

**ADDITIONAL INFORMATION**:

You can set the command param for opening nautilus in any directory you want, for example: `Command = nautilus ~/Downloads` will open nautilus in Downloads directory when CTRL+M is shortcut is used.

**BUG REPORTED:** 
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/1710931

Comment: This doesn't seem to fix the problem at all, just shift it to another key. The bug has been marked obsolete, so a fix seems unlikely

Comment: Thank you! I've been ignoring this annoying message for months now. This solved the issue.

Comment: @wout Same thing for me -- I've been ignoring this message for a few months since getting a new computer. It would be nice to get rid of the error, but long-term switching to ctrl-M is an effective alternative.