# Files window opened with Ctrl+N goes to nonexistent x-nautilus-desktop:///

Tags: keyboard, nautilus, shortcut-keys, 17.10

If I hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>, I get a new Files/Nautilus window, but it comes with this error:
[image: This location could not be displayed. Sorry, could not display all the contents of “x-nautilus-desktop:///”: The specified location in not supported]
I don't really care which folder Files/Nautilus opens, I just want it to open without having to manually close an error dialogue window every time.

This question has been asked [before](https://askubuntu.com/questions/968415/x-nautilus-desktop-error-message-when-opening-nautilus-from-desktop), but the accepted answer doesn't solve the issue in any way. The associated [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/1710931) has been marked *obsolete* despite still being active.

Can the `x-nautilus-desktop:///` shortcut be created somehow to make this issue go away?