# Keyboard Shortcut for New Nautilus Window Error in 18.04

Tags: nautilus, shortcut-keys, 18.04, ubuntu-gnome

In Ubuntu 18.04, When I use the shortcut for opening a new Nautilus window (CTRL + N), I'm getting an error:

> **This location could not be displayed**
>   Sorry, could not display all the contents of "x-nautilus-desktop:///":
>   The specified location is not supported

Below is a link to the image. I'm not allowed to embed images yet, too noob.

This is my first post! :)
[Screenshot of Nautilus Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZEqsR.png)

All locations work fine after clicking "OK" in the error window, but every time I open my first Nautilus window, I always get that same error...and it's killing my flow.

I also tried running Ubuntu from the Bootable install USB and get the same error. I had no problems with the prior stable release, Unity. I'm running on a 2011 Macbook Air, by the way.

Is there a setting I can change to make that error go away?

Comment: I found another thread on this subject. I include "x-nautilus-desktop" when searching on Google and found this thread:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/968415/x-nautilus-desktop-error-message-when-opening-nautilus-from-desktop

Comment: It pointed to the Bug that was reported:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/1710931
Unfortunately, it looks like the status of the bug has been updated to "expired". Based on what Scruss' said, "this will never be fixed, as gnome doesn't think users should have files on the desktop." It's still strange because that shortcut Ctrl + N works on the desktop, triggering Nautilus. If it's not going to be fixed, shouldn't the shortcut at least be deactivated in the desktop environment? Especially for the default LTS Ubuntu install?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [x-nautilus-desktop error message when opening Nautilus from desktop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/968415/x-nautilus-desktop-error-message-when-opening-nautilus-from-desktop)

Comment: A better duplicate may be: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1018865/files-window-opened-with-ctrln-goes-to-nonexistent-x-nautilus-desktop?noredirect=1&lq=1